# How do I know if i'm behind an NTLM proxy?

Tags: proxy, ntlm, http-proxy

Using a computer behind an private corporate proxy, I would like to know if the proxy use or is compatible with NTLM authentication protocol. Any solution working on Windows and/or Linux would be accepted.

Comment: You will in the response headers sent by the proxy that an NTLM authentication is requested. Just send a wget or curl command to the proxy and you'll see what is returned.

Comment: @EugèneAdell Can you provide an example of what that would look like? No matter what I do (provide un/pw or not) I just get "407 Proxy Authentication Required"

Comment: @dainichi The proxy is answering with such a header `Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM`. If using an ordinary browser, open the _developer tools_ and check. Source : [RFC2616 §10.4.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) , [davenport](https://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#theType1Message)